# Angular 7 : Virtual Scrolling and Lazy Loading

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, lazy-loading

How is virtual scrolling different from lazy loading in angular 7? Is there any difference between the two?

Comment: view [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21676579/7541317) answer. hope it will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Virtual Scroll to display the items without slowing the app down**.
Display only small subset of the data that is in the viewport and keep changing the records as the user scrolls. It keep the number of DOM elements constant hence boosting the performance of the application.

**Lazy loading** is the process of loading some features of your Angular application only when you navigate to their routes for the first time. This can be useful for increasing your app performance and decreasing the initial size of the bundle transmitted to the user's browser.